# uwp streamwriter System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, uwp, streamwriter

Hi I'm trying to create a txt file in UWP but I'm getting this error:
`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`: Access to the path......

When I use the code in a Console App it works fine but not in UWP.
I have tried 3 locations to create the txtfile. AppData folder, usb stick, project folder

Here is the code:

```
private void TextMethod()
{
    //string file = @"E:\Logfiles\test.txt";
    //string file = @"C:\Users\deeja\source\repos\UwpTxtTest\UwpTxtTest\bin\x86\Debug\test.txt";
    string file = @"C:\Users\deeja\AppData\test.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(file))
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine();
                Debug.WriteLine("File created");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error = " + e);
        }
    }
    else Debug.WriteLine("File already exists");
}
```

Comment: Does this [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)?

Comment: Hi tttony. I have tried a little of this and it create the file just fine. But it put the file in some random folder. If I can't get the other code to work I will look closer to this again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the file with path in UWP platform, you need to use Windows Storage Api, and enable [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) capability then enable app access the file system in the Setting page (Setting -> Privacy -> File System - >Choose which apps can access your  file system). I have edit code sample below.

```
private async void TextMethod()
{
    //string file = @"E:\Logfiles\test.txt";
    //string file = @"C:\Users\deeja\source\repos\UwpTxtTest\UwpTxtTest\bin\x86\Debug\test.txt";
    string file = @"C:\Users\minghaoz\AppData\test.txt";
    try
    {
        var textFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file);
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var outputStream = await textFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    Debug.WriteLine("File created");
                }
                outputStream.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error = " + e);
       
        if (e.Message.Contains("0x80070002"))
        {
            var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "test";
            savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
            StorageFile newFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
            if (newFile != null)
            {
                CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(newFile);
                // write to file
                using (var outputStream = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                        sw.WriteLine();
                        Debug.WriteLine("File created");
                    }
                    outputStream.Dispose();
                }
                FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(newFile);
                if (status == FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more please refer [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) document.

Comment: Hi Nico. Thank you for your reply. I have now tried your solution and read about capabilities in package manifest. I now dont get the exception however it seems like the if (!File.Exists(file)) part is not working?

Comment: .NET `System.IO` classes don't work outside of your package. You need to use the WinRT API

Comment: @Daniel, Peter's comment is correct, File.Exists(file) will always return false in above scenario, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks it works. I don't understand half of what's going on in the catch block but I will look into it.